# How to access Django crispy tag array within JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, django, django-views, django-crispy-forms

I am working on a Django project. Within one of my apps I want to pass an array of numerical data from my views file to a template. I then want to have access to said data so that I am able to manipulate it within JavaScript.

I can successfully send the array to the template as a crispy tag via the render function. Unfortunately, I can only access said tag within the HTML itself but not within JavaScript.

views.py:

```py
from django.shortcuts import render

sample_data = [1,2,3]

def home(request):
    data = {
        'message': sample_data
        }
    return render(request, 'blog/home.html', data)
```

home.html:

```html
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}
{% block content %}

  <body>

  {{ message|safe }} <!-- can access crispy tag within HTML-->

    <script>
      var x = {{ message|safe }}; // can not access crispytag within javascript
    </script>

  </body>

{% endblock content %}
```

I want to be able access the crispy tag array within the templates' JavaScript. What do I need to change to be able to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need add quotes to access django template tags in javascript

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}
{% block content %}

  <body>

  {{ message|safe }} <!-- can access crispy tag within HTML-->

    <script>
      var x = "{{ message|safe }}" // can not access crispytag within javascript
    </script>

  </body>

{% endblock content %}
```

hope it helps

Comment: That does allow me to access the tag within javascript, thank you. Unfortunately the variable is now a string. For my purposes I need the ``` var x ``` to be an array not a string. Do you know of a way to retain the data type of the original data?